# How to get the path of var folder images in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I have the an images inside var/import/logos folder, how can i get the path of the image to show on the frontend.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Folder `var` is not publicly accessibly from the outside.

You can place the images inside {DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pub/media/import/logos.

Then you can access then by URL.
mydomain.com/pub/media/import/logos/myimage.jpg.

pub/media or media in some magento versions is the default media path for every magento installation.

You can get the media path by injecting `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` in your block and creating a function that gets the media url or returns the full url with the image path you've given

```
public function getImageUrl($path)
{
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add StoreManager Dependency to your file.

```
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
```

and declare the storemanager variable

```
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
```

Place your file to the media folder like media/import/logos/sample.png

```
$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'import/logos/sample.png';
```